# Cannot Connect mysql from php with specific port

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli, database-connection

I have mysql 8.0.15 for windows and I'm trying to connect from remote php webSite but always getting

> 2002: Connection refused

The code I use to test the connection is very simple

```
$dbHost = "HOST";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbDB = "DBNAME";
$dbPort = "9999";
echo "Conectando a $dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbDB,$dbPort ";


$link = mysqli_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbDB,$dbPort);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

I also try host:port and p:host:port and always getting the same error message.

Comment: Sounds to me like the FireWall is keeping you out. You are not actually getting to MySQL yet

Comment: Can you clarify please. Where is running what. Sounds like the database is on your PC and the web site is on a remote hosted server somewhere. Is that right

Comment: There are too many possible duplicates. Please Google the error and try them out.

Comment: Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808332/should-we-ever-check-for-mysqli-connect-errors-manually

Comment: mysql is running in a local PC (not mine) and PHP app is running on website. Connection work perfectly when port is 3306 but not when the port changes

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the MySQL port, you have to edit the `my.ini` config-file on the MySQL server by setting `port=<YOUR PREFERRED PORT>`, then check if the port is forwarded and finally restart the MySQL server.

Comment: No. I want to connect to that port

Comment: Well MySQL listens to port 3306 per default. If you want to connect to your MySQL server from a different port, you have to change the port the server listens to.